# Login form with permissions in access

Tags: ms-access, vba

I've making a simple database with a login form.

I have a tblAccessLevel with AccessLevelID (autonumber) and Accless Level, with a relation to the User Table "tblUsers"
When a new user is added you can select the access level they need.

I;m trying to add a rule so when opening certain forms, it looks at the user logged in and see if they have the correct access level then either allow or deny them.

this is the code i have in place:

```
UserView = DLookup("AccessLevel", "tblUsers", "[curUser] = " & [AccessLevel])
If UserView = "1" Then
Me.Command0.Enabled = True
Else: UserView = "3" Or "2"
Me.Command0.Enabled = False
End If
```

The curUser is defined in the login form:

```
curUser = DLookup("Username", "tblUsers", "[Username]=""" & Me.txtUsername.Value & """")
```

Kind Regards,
Ashley

Main_Form

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
Set dbLog = CurrentDb
Set LogRec = dbLog.OpenRecordset("tblLog")
LogRec.AddNew
LogRec("eDate").Value = Date
LogRec("eTime") = Format(Now, "Long Time")
LogRec("Form").Value = "Main Form"
LogRec("User").Value = curUser
LogRec("Detail").Value = curUser & " Opened Main Form"
LogRec.Update

UserView = DLookup("AccessLevel", "tblUsers", "[curUser] = " & [AccessLevel])

If UserView = 1 Then
Me.Command0.Enabled = True
Else
Me.Command0.Enabled = False
End If

End Sub
```

Form_Login (Login command with code)

```
Public Sub cmdLogin_Click()
Dim dbLog As DAO.Database
Dim LogRec As DAO.Recordset

'Check to see if data is entered into the Username Field
If IsNull(Me.txtUsername) Or Me.txtUsername = "" Then
    MsgBox "You must enter a Username.", vbOKOnly, "Required Data"
    Me.txtUsername.SetFocus
Exit Sub
End If


'Check to see if data is entered into the password box

If IsNull(Me.txtPassword) Or Me.txtPassword = "" Then
MsgBox "You must enter a Password.", vbOKOnly, "Required Data"
Me.txtPassword.SetFocus
Exit Sub
End If

'Check value of password in tblEmplyees to see if this matched value chosen in Username Field

If Me.txtPassword.Value = DLookup("Password", "tblUsers", "[Username]=""" & Me.txtUsername.Value & """") Then
curUser = DLookup("Username", "tblUsers", "[Username]=""" & Me.txtUsername.Value & """")

Set dbLog = CurrentDb
Set LogRec = dbLog.OpenRecordset("tblLog")
LogRec.AddNew
LogRec("eDate").Value = Date
LogRec("eTime") = Format(Now, "Long Time")
LogRec("Form").Value = "Login"
LogRec("User").Value = curUser
LogRec("Detail").Value = "User " & curUser & " Logged in"
LogRec.Update


MyEmpID = Me.txtUsername.Value

'Close Logon form and open splash screen

DoCmd.Close acForm, "frmLogin", acSaveNo
DoCmd.OpenForm "MainForm"

Else

Set dbLog = CurrentDb
Set LogRec = dbLog.OpenRecordset("tblLog")
LogRec.AddNew
LogRec("eDate").Value = Date
LogRec("eTime") = Format(Now, "Long Time")
LogRec("Form").Value = "Login"
LogRec("User").Value = "N/A"
LogRec("Detail").Value = "Someone tried to access your database with an invalid password"
LogRec.Update


MsgBox "Password invalid. Please try again", vbCritical + vbOKOnly, "Invalid Entry!"
Me.txtPassword.SetFocus

End If

'If User Enters incorrect password 3 times database will shutdown
intLogonAttempts = intLogonAttempts + 1
If inLogonAttempts > 3 Then
MsgBox "You do not have access to this database. Please contact your system administrator.", vbCritical, "Restricted Access!"
Application.Quit
End If
End Sub




Private Sub Form_Load()
Set dbLog = CurrentDb
Set LogRec = dbLog.OpenRecordset("tblLog")
LogRec.AddNew
LogRec("eDate").Value = Date
LogRec("eTime") = Format(Now, "Long Time")
LogRec("Form").Value = "Login"
LogRec("User").Value = "N/A"
LogRec("Detail").Value = "Someone logged into your database"
LogRec.Update
End Sub
```

ModCurUser

```
Option Compare Database
Public curUser As Variant
```

ModUserView

```
Option Compare Database
Public UserView As Variant
```

The error is appearing on:

```
UserView = DLookup("AccessLevel", "tblUsers", "[curUser] = " & [AccessLevel])
```

Answer (score 0):

On the assumption 'curUser' is a Global Variable, available to all VBA modules, you could also make 'UserView' a GV. Then, yes, you could have your 'Switchboard' command buttons enabled or disabled based on 'UserView' .  If you worry about creative people simply opening a form manually, then you could add code to your forms like:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
If UserView = 1 Then
    ' no action necessary - allow access
Else
    MsgBox "You do not have permission to use this form"
    DoCmd.Close acForm, Me.Name
End If
End Sub
```

A couple other observations you may be interested in:

1. Variable 'intLogonAttempts' needs to be defined at the Form level - not inside the subroutine. If not, it will never count the attempts correctly (will always be 1).
2. WHen you load the Login form, you say 'N/A' is attempting to log in.  It may be better to track the user-login name or workstation name i.e. Environ$("Username") or Environ("computername")
3. When comparing the password for validation, some applications may want to force a 100% comparision. Currently your test doesn't force users to match the CASE of the password.  The following is a simple solution:

   ```
   If Len(Me.txtPassword.value) = Len(<from your Dlookup>) Then
       For i = 1 To Len(<from your Dlookup>)
           If Asc(Mid$(Me.txtPassword.value, i, 1)) <> Asc(Mid$(<from your Dlookup>, i, 1)) Then
               blnWrongPWD = True
           End If
       Next i
   Else
       blnWrongPWD = True
   End If
   ```

Good Luck, Wayne

Comment: curUser is a module on its own:
Option Compare Database

Public UserView As Variant

Comment: I asked the question incorrectly. I need a certain button available to view if the user has a certain access level

Comment: Was there an issue with the original code you posted? The code you had would enable or disable the button based on the user level. That code could be placed in the Form_Load event.

Comment: I get a Run-Time error 2465: Microsoft Access Can't find the field '|1' referred to in this expression

Comment: Which line of code produces the error? ANd what values are in the variables?  Also, it may be helpful to show the code you are now using.

Comment: I've added my full code above.
I have 3 tables "tblAccessLevel" **AccessLevelID** _Autonumber_ , **Access Level** _Short Text_ , "tblLog" **ID** _AutoNumber_ , **eDate** _Date/Time_ , **eTime** _Date/Time_ , **User** _Short Text_ , **Form** _Short Text_ , **Detail** _Short Text_ . "tblUsers" **EmployeeID** _AutoNumber_ , **UserName** _Short Text_ , **Password** _Short Text_ , **Access Level** _Number_ _Combo lookup from _tblAccessLevel_ .

Comment: But which line of code gets the error AND what value is referenced on that line?

Comment: the error is on:
UserView = DLookup("AccessLevel", "tblUsers", "[curUser] = " & [AccessLevel])

curUser = axs, who's accesslevel is Admin

Comment: I found the problem; you need to use the following line of code:
UserView = DLookup("AccessLevel", "tblUsers", "UserName = '" & curUser & "'")
Also you really should get in the habit of using 'Option Explicit' at the top of your modules, because you will find other issues... like where you have 'intLogonAttempts' and 'inLogonAttempts'...
Hope this helps!!

Comment: Brilliant, that works. When I place Set 'Option Explicit' at the top of the forms it throws a variable error on:

Set dbLog = CurrentDb

Comment: Was `dbLog` declared? ... `Dim dbLog As something` ... if so, what is the something it was declared as?

Comment: No, dbLog, LogRec and MyEmpID need to be defined. I just did:
Dim dbLog       As DAO.Database
Dim LogRec      As DAO.Recordset
Dim MyEmpID     As String

Also, after the dust settles, take a look above in my ANSWER starting with: A couple other observations you may be interested in: